# Windows Phone 7 & 8 support not working

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to support both WP7 & WP8 in a same solution to use more recent libraries on recent devices. However, it doesnt seem to work...

Here is what i did :

- Copied the project folder, renamed it and the project name inside of it to projectName8
- Added a new project (the copy) into the solution
- Upgraded the new project to WP8
- Added the WP8 tag in the build settings of the windows 8 one
- Deleted the MainView.xaml file from new one and linked the other projects one
- Added a control loop like `#if WP8 XXXXX #else YYYYYY #endif`

However, when I debug the app on a windows 8 phone, the YYYYY instruction is called.... I really don't know how it comes and this is really boring... I noticed something wierd : In my code, only the `YYYYY` istruction is grayed. The other one is in normal color. Mabe is it a syntax error but I couldn't tell you.

```
#if WP8
            currentScore.Text="heho"; //Normal color
#else
            currentScore.Text="WP7"; //Gray color <=This line is called only
#endif
```

Comment: Are you sure you added the WP8 tag to every build configurations (debug, release, etc.)?

Comment: Yes I did ! I am wondering if the "debug" button isn't linked to the wp7 project rather than the whole solution... How can I check that ?

Comment: Make sure you set the WP8 project as Startup project (right click on the project)

Comment: I will check that. Ty vm. Regarding the WP8 tag, will it be up on the release version or do I need to do something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you can check the OS version programmatically:

```
bool WP8 = Environment.OSVersion.Version.CompareTo(new Version(8, 0)) >= 0;
```

Of course, your code will always need to be compilant for WP7.